# Regex as a command line arg for filtering lines with a particular value

Tags: regex, perl

I want to be able to take an argument from the command line and use it as a regular expression within my script to filter lines from my file. A simple example

```
$ perl script.pl id_4
```

In script.pl:

```
...
my $exp = shift;
while(my $line = <$fh){
    if($line =~ /$exp/){
        print $line,"\n";
    }
}
...
```

My actual script is a bit more complicated and does other manipulations to the line to extract information and produce a different output. My problem is that I have situations where I want to filter out every line that contains "id_4" instead of only select lines containing "id_4". Normally this could be achieved by

```
if($line !~ /$exp/)
```

but, if possible, I don't want to alter my script to accept a more complex set of arguments (e.g. use `!~` if second parameter is "ne", and `=~` if not).

Can anyone think of a regex that I can use (beside a long "id_1|id_2|id_3|id_5...") to filter out lines containing one particular value out of many possibilities? I fear I'm asking for the daft here, and should probably just stick to the sensible and accept a further argument :/.

Comment: Frankly, I would recommend a "not" (or `-v` in grep parlance) argument that you proposed as the best option. Don't over-complicate the code for the sake of false elegance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why choose? Have both.

```
my $exp = join "|", grep !/^!/, @ARGV;
my @not = grep /^!/,  @ARGV;
s/^!// for @not;
my $exp_not = join "|", @not;

...
if (( $line =~ $exp ) && ( $line !~ $exp_not )) {
    # do stuff
}
```

**Usage:**

```
perl script.pl orange soda !light !diet
```

Comment: Didn't even realise a grep-like function was implemented in perl. Amazing!

Comment: @kikumbob I can recommend [perldoc perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html), it's an interesting read. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to invert regular expressions, so you can do matches like "all strings which do not contain a match for `subexpr`". Without the operators which express this directly (i.e. using only the basic positive-matching regex operators), it is still possible but leads to large and unwieldy regular expressions (possibly, combinatorial explosion in the regex size).

For a simple example, look at my answer to this question: how to write a regex which matches everything but the string "help". (It's a quite a simplification that the match is anchored to start and end.) [Match all letter/number combos but specific word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625694/match-all-letter-number-combos-but-specific-word/9628057#9628057)

Traditional Unix tools have hacks for situations when you want to just invert the match of the expression as a whole: `grep` versus `grep -v`. Or `vi`: `:g/pat/` versus `:v/pat/`, etc. In this way, the implementors ducked out implementing the difficult regex operators that don't fit into the simple NFA construction approach.

The easiest thing is to do the same thing and have a convention for coarse-grained negation: an include pattern and an exclude pattern.

Comment: Of course, since Perl supports negative lookahead assertions (e.g. `/^(?!.*id_5)/`), that sort of complexity is not actually necessary. :-)